# ButtomSheet of Material Design does not show properly - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, material-components-ios

I was trying to integrate my app with `material-components` called `bottomSheet`. When i implement that component it shown me correctly but not like what i expected.

When it shown up and all the time i scroll up that bottomSheet does not stick to bottom of view

Here it looks like
[image]

How to fix this particular issue?

Here is the code

```
let viewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()

    viewController.view.backgroundColor = .red
    let bottomSheet: MDCBottomSheetController = MDCBottomSheetController(contentViewController: viewController)

    self.present(bottomSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't add some contents of that particular viewController.

Create `tableViewController`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TableViewContent: UITableViewController {

  let cellId = "CellId"
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

  }

  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return 1
  }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return 10
  }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello World"
    return cell
  }

}
```

After created that controller 
then add this in your code that you provided:

```
 //       let viewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
//
//        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .red
//        let size = viewController.view.sizeThatFits(view.bounds.size)
//        let viewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
//        viewController.view.frame = viewFrame

    let viewController = TableViewContent()

    let bottomSheet: MDCBottomSheetController = MDCBottomSheetController(contentViewController: viewController)

    self.present(bottomSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this will help...
The reason it not stick to bottom because the controller is empty, just my idea...

Comment: Hello I need help on this ,Same above issues i am facing with CollectionViewController,And if i am using the tableViewController as Explained above everything works fine as expected.